# how do I set a minimum scalable value for a ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview, scale

let's say I have an image 'A' with 400x400 res in my drawable folder, I have a ImageView source set to A, this ImageView is inside a linear layout or a card layout.

I want the image to scale depending on the device, I want it to be say 120dp X 120dp for a 4-Inch device, but I want it to scale to bigger pixels depending on the size of the display

[image]

Comment: you can use a LinearLayout + weight, and scale type of fitCenter in your ImageView, or some ConstraintLayout magic (which for sure will work even better, but i don't know how to use it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using constrain layout and setting image width and height to 0dp which makes it scale according to the image source size.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the resolution of your device, do it like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Then, according to the width and height, you can set ImageView.SetWidth(...) / Height / ScaleType by using certain statements.

Comment: is it better to do this or to make a new layout for lower dpi in these folders

`res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml

res/layout-large/main_activity.xml

res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use ScaleType in ImageView centerInside.

Or

You can Make new `Bitmap` according screen size by maintaining `Aspect Ratio`.

Suppose your Image Size is 400x300 (WxH)

And your expected `ImageView` Size is 200x400

And you want to fit it according width of `ImageView` Then you will calculate new `Height` and `Width` by using below formula and resize new `Bitmap`.

> Aspect Ratio = Height / Width (if we taken new Width)
>
> Aspect Ratio = Width / Height (If we take new Height)

AR= 300/400 = 0.75

```
New Height = NewWidth * AR;
NewHeight = 200 * 0.75;
NewHeight = 150 ;
```

So you can resize Bitmap as by taking above height and width.

[Online Image Aspect Ratio Calculator](https://red-route.org/code/image-resizing-calculator)

Use below method to resize Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, new Paint());
return output;
}
```